# AWS Cognito - how to create a backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, backup, amazon-cognito

We are currently moving our Auth services to AWS Cognito. As it's crucial to have the user profiles + data safe, we need to have a backup of the main user pool. We've noticed that there is an option to  Import Users via a .csv file with the headers equal to the pool attributes but there is no option to create the .csv automatically. Does anyone know of a solution which automatically generates such file?The point is to protect the user profiles of accidental delete of the whole user pool (by accident, let's say a tired developer on Friday night)? I've personally tried to implement a workaround solution by doing all manual work (getting headers, users, mapping them and creating the csv) but that is not very reliable.

Answer (score 12):

I know I am late to the party but leaving this here for future searches.

I too faced the same issue while working with Cognito and thus made a tool to take backups and restore them to userpools.

**You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup-restore**

This can be used via [cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup-restore#cli) or using [imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup-restore#imports) (incase you want to write your own wrapper or script). 
Please suggest any improvements: https://github.com/rahulpsd18/cognito-backup-restore

---

This is still under development, as I plan to make use of **Cognito User Pool Import Job** instead of using `aws-sdk's adminCreateUser` to create users while restoring to improve upon the current implementation. But it works fine for now.

**Cross-Region Cognito Replication** will be implemented too once I fine tune the restore process.

Comment: Hi, 
what about password? You cant fetch user password from Cognito, right?

Comment: Cognito stores a salt and a verifier for the password you signed up with and doesn't store it in the form you entered it. It also doesn't give access to it either. So, no you can't fetch user password from cognito. The best you can do is ask your users to make use of reset password to set a new password.

Comment: Great package. Does it restore the id/sub property or is that re-created for each record with a new id?

Answer (score 9):

Amazon has released a [Cognito User Profiles Export Reference Architecture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/cognito-user-profiles-export-reference-architecture/welcome.html) for exporting/importing users from a user pool. There are [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/cognito-user-profiles-export-reference-architecture/solution-components.html):

- Passwords not backed up; users will need to reset
- Pools using MFA are not supported
- Cognito sub attributes will be new, so if the system depends on them, they need to be copied to a custom user attribute
- Federated users also pose challenges WRT sub
- Advanced security - no user history is exported
- No support for pools that allow the option of either phone or email usernames
- No support for tracked devices

Answer (score 4):

I also created a tool for this, which also supports backing up and restoring groups and relations to users:

https://github.com/mifi/cognito-backup

You can install it like this:

```
npm i -g cognito-backup
```

and use it like this:

```
cognito-backup backup-users eu-west-1_1_12345
cognito-backup backup-groups eu-west-1_1_12345
cognito-backup backup-all-users eu-west-1_1_12345

cognito-backup restore-groups eu-west-1_12345
cognito-backup restore-users eu-west-1_12345 Abcd.1234 --file eu-west-1_12345.json
```

Note that password cannot be backed up due to an AWS limitation.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent accidental pool deletion you could create a [Service Control Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) at the org level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).